# Undefined reference with Eclipse for source in different directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-errors, g++, linker-errors

I have an old source which I need to integrate in my project in Eclipse (in Ubuntu 12.04). 
The old source code works perfectly on its own. But the only problem with it is - I have just one .cpp file (which contains the main) and all others are .h files which contains the definitions and declarations. I fixed this by creating a source file for each header file and copying the function definitions in these files and left the declarations in the header files.
I added these files using eclipse so those files actually are getting compiled.

Note that, I have added this source code into "src/segment". Here is my directory listing. These files also show up in the eclipse project. My main function is in "HelloOpenCV2.cpp"

```
[eeuser@roadrunner src]$ ls
CameraPoseFromFundamentalMatrix.d  InterestPoints.o
CameraPoseFromFundamentalMatrix.o  LinesAndComponents.d
GLViz.d                            LinesAndComponents.o
GLViz.o                            MorphologicalManip.d
GraphImageSegmentation.d           MorphologicalManip.o
GraphImageSegmentation.o           MultiviewColorConsistency.d
HelloOpenCV2.d                     MultiviewColorConsistency.o
HelloOpenCV2.o                     segment
HomographyWarp.d                   StereoCamDepth.d
HomographyWarp.o                   StereoCamDepth.o
ImageManipulations.d               subdir.mk
ImageManipulations.o               VideoProc.d
InterestPoints.d                   VideoProc.o
[eeuser@roadrunner src]$ ls segment/
convolve.d      filter.d  imconv.d  segment-graph.d  subdir.mk
convolve.o      filter.o  imconv.o  segment-graph.o
disjoint-set.d  image.d   imutil.d  segment-image.d
disjoint-set.o  image.o   imutil.o  segment-image.o
```

Here is my compilation log as generated by eclipse.

```
18:54:21 **** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloOpenCV2 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/segment/convolve.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/segment/convolve.d" -MT"src/segment/convolve.d" -o "src/segment/convolve.o" "../src/segment/convolve.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/segment/convolve.cpp

Building file: ../src/segment/disjoint-set.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/segment/disjoint-set.d" -MT"src/segment/disjoint-set.d" -o "src/segment/disjoint-set.o" "../src/segment/disjoint-set.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/segment/disjoint-set.cpp

Building file: ../src/segment/filter.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/segment/filter.d" -MT"src/segment/filter.d" -o "src/segment/filter.o" "../src/segment/filter.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/segment/filter.cpp

Building file: ../src/segment/image.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/segment/image.d" -MT"src/segment/image.d" -o "src/segment/image.o" "../src/segment/image.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/segment/image.cpp

Building file: ../src/segment/imconv.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/segment/imconv.d" -MT"src/segment/imconv.d" -o "src/segment/imconv.o" "../src/segment/imconv.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/segment/imconv.cpp

Building file: ../src/segment/imutil.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/segment/imutil.d" -MT"src/segment/imutil.d" -o "src/segment/imutil.o" "../src/segment/imutil.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/segment/imutil.cpp

Building file: ../src/segment/segment-graph.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/segment/segment-graph.d" -MT"src/segment/segment-graph.d" -o "src/segment/segment-graph.o" "../src/segment/segment-graph.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/segment/segment-graph.cpp

Building file: ../src/segment/segment-image.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/segment/segment-image.d" -MT"src/segment/segment-image.d" -o "src/segment/segment-image.o" "../src/segment/segment-image.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/segment/segment-image.cpp

Building file: ../src/CameraPoseFromFundamentalMatrix.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/CameraPoseFromFundamentalMatrix.d" -MT"src/CameraPoseFromFundamentalMatrix.d" -o "src/CameraPoseFromFundamentalMatrix.o" "../src/CameraPoseFromFundamentalMatrix.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/CameraPoseFromFundamentalMatrix.cpp

Building file: ../src/GLViz.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/GLViz.d" -MT"src/GLViz.d" -o "src/GLViz.o" "../src/GLViz.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/GLViz.cpp

Building file: ../src/GraphImageSegmentation.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/GraphImageSegmentation.d" -MT"src/GraphImageSegmentation.d" -o "src/GraphImageSegmentation.o" "../src/GraphImageSegmentation.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/GraphImageSegmentation.cpp

Building file: ../src/HelloOpenCV2.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/HelloOpenCV2.d" -MT"src/HelloOpenCV2.d" -o "src/HelloOpenCV2.o" "../src/HelloOpenCV2.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/HelloOpenCV2.cpp

Building file: ../src/HomographyWarp.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/HomographyWarp.d" -MT"src/HomographyWarp.d" -o "src/HomographyWarp.o" "../src/HomographyWarp.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/HomographyWarp.cpp

Building file: ../src/ImageManipulations.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/ImageManipulations.d" -MT"src/ImageManipulations.d" -o "src/ImageManipulations.o" "../src/ImageManipulations.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/ImageManipulations.cpp

Building file: ../src/InterestPoints.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/InterestPoints.d" -MT"src/InterestPoints.d" -o "src/InterestPoints.o" "../src/InterestPoints.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/InterestPoints.cpp

Building file: ../src/LinesAndComponents.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/LinesAndComponents.d" -MT"src/LinesAndComponents.d" -o "src/LinesAndComponents.o" "../src/LinesAndComponents.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/LinesAndComponents.cpp

Building file: ../src/MorphologicalManip.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/MorphologicalManip.d" -MT"src/MorphologicalManip.d" -o "src/MorphologicalManip.o" "../src/MorphologicalManip.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/MorphologicalManip.cpp

Building file: ../src/MultiviewColorConsistency.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/MultiviewColorConsistency.d" -MT"src/MultiviewColorConsistency.d" -o "src/MultiviewColorConsistency.o" "../src/MultiviewColorConsistency.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/MultiviewColorConsistency.cpp

Building file: ../src/StereoCamDepth.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/StereoCamDepth.d" -MT"src/StereoCamDepth.d" -o "src/StereoCamDepth.o" "../src/StereoCamDepth.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/StereoCamDepth.cpp

Building file: ../src/VideoProc.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -w -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/VideoProc.d" -MT"src/VideoProc.d" -o "src/VideoProc.o" "../src/VideoProc.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/VideoProc.cpp

Building target: HelloOpenCV2
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "HelloOpenCV2"  ./src/segment/convolve.o ./src/segment/disjoint-set.o ./src/segment/filter.o ./src/segment/image.o ./src/segment/imconv.o ./src/segment/imutil.o ./src/segment/segment-graph.o ./src/segment/segment-image.o  ./src/CameraPoseFromFundamentalMatrix.o ./src/GLViz.o ./src/GraphImageSegmentation.o ./src/HelloOpenCV2.o ./src/HomographyWarp.o ./src/ImageManipulations.o ./src/InterestPoints.o ./src/LinesAndComponents.o ./src/MorphologicalManip.o ./src/MultiviewColorConsistency.o ./src/StereoCamDepth.o ./src/VideoProc.o   -lopencv_core -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_flann  -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
../src/segment/filter.cpp:39: error: undefined reference to 'image<float>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/filter.cpp:40: error: undefined reference to 'image<float>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/filter.cpp:41: error: undefined reference to 'convolve_even(image<float>*, image<float>*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&)'
../src/segment/filter.cpp:42: error: undefined reference to 'convolve_even(image<float>*, image<float>*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&)'
../src/segment/filter.cpp:44: error: undefined reference to 'image<float>::~image()'
../src/segment/filter.cpp:52: error: undefined reference to 'imageUCHARtoFLOAT(image<unsigned char>*)'
../src/segment/filter.cpp:54: error: undefined reference to 'image<float>::~image()'
../src/segment/filter.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'image<float>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:15: error: undefined reference to 'image<unsigned char>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:31: error: undefined reference to 'image<rgb>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:46: error: undefined reference to 'image<float>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:73: error: undefined reference to 'image<unsigned char>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:90: error: undefined reference to 'void min_max<float>(image<float>*, float*, float*)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:97: error: undefined reference to 'image<long>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:110: error: undefined reference to 'image<unsigned char>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:127: error: undefined reference to 'void min_max<long>(image<long>*, long*, long*)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:135: error: undefined reference to 'image<unsigned char>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/imconv.cpp:152: error: undefined reference to 'void min_max<short>(image<short>*, short*, short*)'
../src/segment/segment-image.cpp:62: error: undefined reference to 'smooth(image<float>*, float)'
../src/segment/segment-image.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'smooth(image<float>*, float)'
../src/segment/segment-image.cpp:64: error: undefined reference to 'smooth(image<float>*, float)'
../src/segment/segment-image.cpp:65: error: undefined reference to 'image<float>::~image()'
../src/segment/segment-image.cpp:66: error: undefined reference to 'image<float>::~image()'
../src/segment/segment-image.cpp:120: error: undefined reference to 'image<rgb>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/segment-image.cpp:121: error: undefined reference to 'image<int>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/pnmfile.h:166: error: undefined reference to 'image<rgb>::image(int, int, bool)'
../src/segment/pnmfile.h:166: error: undefined reference to 'image<rgb>::image(int, int, bool)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HelloOpenCV2] Error 1

18:54:30 Build Finished (took 8s.826ms)
```

I can also confirm that .o (object) files for each of the source files are generated. However, I do not understand how to fix the undefined reference error.

Would like to add that the file image.cpp / image.h contain a class definition. I have not added these 2 files as add->class have added them as add->source and add->header

Just applied "nm" command on image.o. Got an empty response. Although image.o is a 24 byte file.

image.h contains the template class declaration and image.cpp contains class function definition.

Image is a template class. The header and source for it are as -

```
/*
 * image.h
 *
 *  Created on: 25 Oct, 2014
 *      Author: eeuser
 */

#ifndef IMAGE_H_
#define IMAGE_H_

#include <cstring>

/* use imRef to access image data. */
#define imRef(im, x, y) (im->access[y][x])

/* use imPtr to get pointer to image data. */
#define imPtr(im, x, y) &(im->access[y][x])


template <class T>
class image {
public:
     /* create an image */
      image(int width, int height, bool init = true);

      /* delete an image */
      ~image();

      /* init an image */
      void init(const T &val);

      /* copy an image */
      image<T> *copy() const;

      /* get the width of an image. */
      int width() const { return w; }

      /* get the height of an image. */
      int height() const { return h; }

      /* image data. */
      T *data;

      /* row pointers. */
      T **access;

     private:
      int w, h;
};

#endif /* IMAGE_H_ */
```

The source:

```
/*
 * image.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 25 Oct, 2014
 *      Author: eeuser
 */

#include "image.h"


template <class T>
image<T>::image(int width, int height, bool init) {
  w = width;
  h = height;
  data = new T[w * h];  // allocate space for image data
  access = new T*[h];   // allocate space for row pointers

  // initialize row pointers
  for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    access[i] = data + (i * w);

  if (init)
    memset(data, 0, w * h * sizeof(T));
}

template <class T>
image<T>::~image() {
  delete [] data;
  delete [] access;
}

template <class T>
void image<T>::init(const T &val) {
  T *ptr = imPtr(this, 0, 0);
  T *end = imPtr(this, w-1, h-1);
  while (ptr <= end)
    *ptr++ = val;
}


template <class T>
image<T> *image<T>::copy() const {
  image<T> *im = new image<T>(w, h, false);
  memcpy(im->data, data, w * h * sizeof(T));
  return im;
}
```

I turned on the extra warning flags in g++ (-Wextra). It complained about a bunch of static functions I had. I just changed those to normal functions. I guess this is ok, since those functions were not associated with a class.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't require you to have .cpp files for every .h file. In other words, you can have one .cpp file (which includes main()) and all the others files to be header files. I suspect you missed something when creating the source files for your header files, since the bug log shows that some functions (e.g. `image<float>::image(int, int, bool)`) are not visible. did you included the corresponding header file to the source file?

Comment: yes, I have included all the corresponding headers in the source files in addition to other header that might be required

Comment: Well, if you are sure that the code is OK, then I'd suggest you to delete this project, create a new one, with one source file and all the other files to be header files (as you had before), build and see what happens.

Comment: actually, if I have all the source in the headers (as before) I get the "multiple declarations" error. This is the reason I originally split the source and declarations into separate files.

Comment: I already have #ifndef in each of my header files already